# Using cfif in coldfusion

Tags: xml, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

For example, please consider the following code snippet:

**Scenario 1:**

The company name I received as a part of SOAP response is as follows:

```
<Company>Amazon, Inc </Company>
```

**Scenario 2:**

Another company name I received as a part of SOAP response is as follows:

```
<Company>Google, Inc </Company>
```

Basically, from the user end I am inputting some information and based on that I am getting different company names inside the `<Company>` tag.

The following code shows how I am storing the response in XMLResponse variable

```
 <cfset XMLResponse = XmlParse(

    httpResponse.fileContent.Trim()

    ) />
```

The following piece of code shows how I am parsing the response and storing the content in a variable:

```
<cfset arrCOMPANY = XmlSearch(
             XMLResponse,
             "//*[name()='Company']"
             ) />
```

So now I have arrCOMPANY = Amazon, Inc is I happen to be in Scenario and Google, Inc otherwise.

**My Question:**

I have to insert these data into the database based on the company name and set an integer field to be equal to 1 if the company name is Amazon,Inc 
and set it to zero otherwise for all other companies.

Please let me know if I am following the right path:

I am thinking of writing two cfqueries based on the company names and hence I am thinking to place the following condition :

```
<cfif arrCompany eq "Amazon, Inc">

// Here I will write cfquery with an integer field = 1


Or 

<cfif arrCompany eq "Google, Inc">

// Here I will write cfquery with integer field 0
```

So, am I doing the right comparision, I am wondering whether the company names that I am comparing with eq sign will be actually compared or not as 
it contains spaces after first word ( say for example the space between Amazon, and Inc).

Please share your experience.

Thanks

Here is what I did:

I have applied trim function on specific element as well. For example:

The Value in the CompanyName variable is `Amazon, Inc`

```
<cfset CompanyName = Trim(arrCompany[1])>  // adding index 1 because  it's a complex structure
```

Here is how I am trying to use cfif condition:

```
<cfif CompanyName eq "Amazon, Inc">

    <cfset m = 1>

    <cfelse>

    <cfset m = 0>  

    </cfif> 

    <cfoutput>#m#</cfoutput>
```

Despite doing above, I am getting `0` as my output. Please let me know if I am comparing wrong.

Comment: You do not need separate queries just to set a bit flag. What is the issue you are experiencing? If the node contains the *exact* value `Amazon, Inc` it will be considered equal. Is something different happening in your actual code?

Comment: Try an output of the companyName between quotes so that you can see what is the exact trimmed value. <cfoutput>'#companyName#'</cfoutput>. the quotes will help to see if there is any more characters that trim cannot remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `<cfset CompanyName = Trim(arrCompany[1])>`

If you `cfdump` that variable, or wrap it in `xmlFormat()`, you will see it contains the whole node, not just the text. It is easy to miss when using only `cfoutput`, because the browser treats the xml as tags, so they are not visible unless you view the source:

```
<cfoutput>#XMLFormat(CompanyName)#</cfoutput>
```

To grab only the node text use the `xmlText` attribute, then trim it:

```
<cfset CompanyName = trim( arrCompany[1].xmlText )>
```

**Edit:**  Also, as mentioned in the comments, you do not need separate queries just to set a `bit` flag. Simply set a CF variable to 1 or 0, based on the company name, then use it in your query.

Comment: Also, consider using more descriptive variable names *throughout* the code. For example, instead of `m` a better name for the boolean flag might be `isAmazon`.

Answer (score 0):

The trim function only works on the entire XML fragment. You want to:

```
<cfset arrCOMPANY = trim(XmlSearch(
         XMLResponse,
         "//*[name()='Company']"
         )) />
```

Having said that you many want to consider

a) Having the database do the translation from string to integer
OR
b) Storing the whole extracted string
OR
c) Storing the whole XML fragment

Comment: Thanks. Please check my updated question with the problem I am facing now. Thanks

Comment: When I have two strings that I think match but don't, I do a quick sanity check with Len(), it that doesn't reveal anything, I might `<cfoutput>` both strings, run the page, save the results into a text file, and compare with a hex editor. Last but not least, I would try something tacky like `<cfset arrCompany="#arrCompany#">`