# Tackling Null Values while Inserting data in data base

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfquery

I have the following `cfquery`:

```
<cfquery name="CQuery" datasource="XX.X.X.XXX">
        INSERT INTO DatabaseName 
            (PhoneNumber_vch,
             Company_vch,
             date_dt)

         VALUES(#PhoneNumber#,
            #Company#,
            #Date# )

    </cfquery>
```

There are null values in case Company name doesnt' exist and I believe becasue of that Iam getting the following error:

```
 Error Executing Database Query.
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

The comma `,` pointed in the error message is after  `#Company#` field. Please let me know is it's because of null values and best approach to fix it?

The values in the PhoneNumber, company and Date are extracted from a XML SOAP response with proper usage of trim function as discussed in my previous post.

[Using cfif in coldfusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659902/using-cfif-in-coldfusion/19680151?noredirect=1#comment29248970_19680151)

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure phone numbers are numbers and not strings?

Comment: Switching to `cfqueryparam` is definitely the way to go. The cfsqltypes vary depending on the data types of your columns. For dates, use `cf_sql_timestamp` when dealing with a date **and** time, or `cf_sql_date` when dealing with a date *only*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you use CFQueryParam like you should on any database SQL that accepts dynamic parameters you can kill two birds with one stone. First and most important, prevent SQL Injection Attacks and second you can use the attribute of the null="" to insert a NULL value into your record.

```
 <cfquery name="CQuery" datasource="XX.X.X.XXX">
      INSERT INTO DatabaseName (PhoneNumber_vch, Company_vch, date_dt)
      VALUES(
           <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#trim(PhoneNumber)#" null="#NOT len(trim(PhoneNumber))#" />
           ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#trim(Company)#" null="#NOT len(trim(Company))#" />
           ,<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#Date#" null="#NOT len(trim(Date))#" />
     )
</cfquery>
```

Comment: @Jack - Keep in mind a `null` is different than an empty string "". Using `cfqueryparam` you could simply insert the empty string instead of a `null`. (At least for the `varchar` columns). It all depends on your goal, and whether the columns allow nulls.

Comment: For the timestamp field, I'd change the null attribute to use isDate() on the date variable instead of len().

Answer (score 4):

You will want to use `<cfqueryparam>`  to take care of nulls (and injection attacks)

Try

```
<cfquery name="CQuery" datasource="XX.X.X.XXX">
    INSERT INTO DatabaseName 
        (PhoneNumber_vch,
         Company_vch,
         date_dt)

     VALUES(
        <cfqueryparam value = "#PhoneNumber#" cfsqltype = "CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
        <cfqueryparam value = "#Company#" cfsqltype = "CF_SQL_VARCHAR" 
          null              = "#IIF(Company EQ "", 1, 0)#">,
        <cfqueryparam value = "#Date#" cfsqltype = "CF_SQL_TimeStamp"
          null              = "#IIF(Date EQ "", 1, 0)#" >
        )

</cfquery>
```

Also see: [cfqueryparam](/questions/tagged/cfqueryparam)

Comment: You probably want a null attribute on the date variable as well.

Answer (score 3):

You either need to qualify your varchar entries (surround all varchar entries with single quotes, or, better would be change them to cfqueryparams;

```
<cfquery name="CQuery" datasource="XX.X.X.XXX">
        INSERT INTO DatabaseName 
            (PhoneNumber_vch,
             Company_vch,
             date_dt)

         VALUES(<cfqueryparam value="#PhoneNumber#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
            <cfqueryparam value="#Company#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
            <cfqueryparam value="#Date#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP"> )

    </cfquery>
```